# Multiple folds in one pass using generic tuple function

Tags: haskell, ghc, fold, higher-order-functions

How can I write a function which takes a tuple of functions of type `ai -> b -> ai` and returns a function which takes a tuple of elements of type `ai`, one element of type `b`, and combines each of the elements into a new tuple of `ai`:

That is the signature should be like

```
f :: (a1 -> b -> a1, a2 -> b -> a2, ... , an -> b -> an) -> 
     (a1, a2, ... , an) -> 
     b -> 
     (a1, a2, ... , an)
```

Such that:

```
f (min, max, (+), (*)) (1,2,3,4) 5 = (1, 5, 8, 20)
```

The point of this is so I can write:

```
foldlMult' t = foldl' (f t)
```

And then do something like:

```
foldlMult' (min, max, (+), (*)) (head x, head x, 0, 0) x
```

to do multiple folds in one pass. GHC extensions are okay.

Comment: I think there's a solution using Arrow's *** and &&&, using types like (f,(g,(h,i))) instead of (f,g,h,i) under the hood, but I'm a couple of hundred miles away from my laptop at the moment so can't play today.

Answer (score 11):

If I understand your examples right, the types are `ai -> b -> ai`, not `ai -> b -> a` as you first wrote.  Let's rewrite the types to `a -> ri -> ri`, just because it helps me think.

First thing to observe is this correspondence:

```
(a -> r1 -> r1, ..., a -> rn -> rn) ~ a -> (r1 -> r1, ..., rn -> rn)
```

This allows you to write these two functions, which are inverses:

```
pullArg :: (a -> r1 -> r1, a -> r2 -> r2) -> a -> (r1 -> r1, r2 -> r2)
pullArg (f, g) = \a -> (f a, g a)

pushArg :: (a -> (r1 -> r1, r2 -> r2)) -> (a -> r1 -> r1, a -> r2 -> r2) 
pushArg f = (\a -> fst (f a), \a -> snd (f a))
```

Second observation: types of the form `ri -> ri` are sometimes called *endomorphisms*, and each of these types has a monoid with composition as the associative operation and the identity function as the identity.  The `Data.Monoid` package has this wrapper for that:

```
newtype Endo a = Endo { appEndo :: a -> a }

instance Monoid (Endo a) where
    mempty = id
    mappend = (.)
```

This allows you to rewrite the earlier `pullArg` to this:

```
pullArg :: (a -> r1 -> r1, a -> r2 -> r2) -> a -> (Endo r1, Endo r2)
pullArg (f, g) = \a -> (Endo $ f a, Endo $ g a)
```

Third observation: the product of two monoids is also a monoid, as per this instance also from `Data.Monoid`:

```
instance (Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monoid (a, b) where
    mempty = (mempty, mempty)
    (a, b) `mappend` (c, d) = (a `mappend` c, b `mappend d)
```

Likewise for tuples of any number of arguments.

Fourth observation: [What are folds made of?](http://web.jaguarpaw.co.uk/~tom/blog/posts/2012-11-04-what-is-foldr-made-of.html)  Answer: [folds are made of monoids!](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/foldr-is-made-of-monoids/)

```
import Data.Monoid

fold :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> [a] -> m
fold f = mconcat . map f
```

This `fold` is just a specialization of `foldMap` from `Data.Foldable`, so in reality we don't need to define it, we can just import its more general version:

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

If you `fold` with `Endo`, that's the same as folding from the right.  To fold from the left, you want to fold with the `Dual (Endo r)` monoid:

```
myfoldl :: (a -> Dual (Endo r)) -> r -> -> [a] -> r
myfoldl f z xs = appEndo (getDual (fold f xs)) z


-- From `Data.Monoid`.  This just flips the order of `mappend`.
newtype Dual m = Dual { getDual :: m }

instance Monoid m => Monoid (Dual m) where
    mempty = Dual mempty
    Dual a `mappend` Dual b = Dual $ b `mappend` a
```

Remember our `pullArg` function?  Let's revise it a bit more, since you're folding from the left:

```
pullArg :: (a -> r1 -> r1, a -> r2 -> r2) -> a -> Dual (Endo r1, Endo r2)
pullArg (f, g) = \a -> Dual (Endo $ f a, Endo $ g a)
```

And this, I claim, is the 2-tuple version of your `f`, or at least isomorphic to it.  You can refactor your fold functions into the form `a -> Endo ri`, and then do:

```
let (f'1, ..., f'n) = foldMap (pullArgn f1 ... fn) xs
in (f'1 z1, ..., f'n zn)
```

Also worth looking at: [Composable Streaming Folds](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/08/composable-streaming-folds.html), which is a further elaboration of these ideas.

Answer (score 6):

For a direct approach, you can just define the equivalents of `Control.Arrow`'s `(***)` and `(&&&)` explicitly, for each `N` (e.g. `N == 4`):

```
prod4 (f1,f2,f3,f4) (x1,x2,x3,x4) = (f1 x1,f2 x2,f3 x3,f4 x4)   -- cf (***)
call4 (f1,f2,f3,f4)  x            = (f1 x, f2 x, f3 x, f4 x )   -- cf (&&&)
uncurry4    f       (x1,x2,x3,x4) =  f  x1    x2    x3    x4
```

Then,

```
foldr4 :: (b -> a1 -> a1, b -> a2 -> a2, 
            b -> a3 -> a3, b -> a4 -> a4)
       -> (a1, a2, a3, a4) -> [b] 
       -> (a1, a2, a3, a4)                        -- (f .: g) x y = f (g x y)
foldr4 t z xs = foldr (prod4 . call4 t) z xs      -- foldr . (prod4 .: call4) 
              -- f x1 (f x2 (... (f xn z) ...))   -- foldr . (($)   .: ($))
```

So the tuple's functions in `foldr4`'s are flipped versions of what you wanted. Testing:

> Prelude> g xs = foldr4 (min, max, (+), (*)) (head xs, head xs, 0, 1) xs 
>   Prelude> g [1..5] 
>   (1,5,15,120)

`foldl4'` is a tweak away. Since

```
foldr f z xs == foldl (\k x r-> k (f x r)) id xs z
foldl f z xs == foldr (\x k a-> k (f a x)) id xs z
```

we have

```
foldl4, foldl4' :: (t -> a -> t, t1 -> a -> t1,
                    t2 -> a -> t2, t3 -> a -> t3)
                -> (t, t1, t2, t3) -> [a] 
                -> (t, t1, t2, t3)
foldl4 t z xs = foldr (\x k a-> k (call4 (prod4 t a) x)) 
                      (prod4 (id,id,id,id)) xs z
foldl4' t z xs = foldr (\x k a-> k (call4 (prod4' t a) x)) 
                       (prod4 (id,id,id,id)) xs z
prod4' (f1,f2,f3,f4) (x1,x2,x3,x4) = (f1 $! x1,f2 $! x2,f3 $! x3,f4 $! x4)
```

We've even got the types as you wanted, for the tuple's functions.

A stricter version of `prod4` had to be used to force the arguments early in `foldl4'`.